# Determine a base of the orthogonal complement. Determine orthogonal projection.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I just want to check is my method of solving the next problem is correct (Please, tell me if something in text is unclear. My mathematical English isn't best.):

The problem:

In vector space $\Bbb{R}_2[x] = \{ p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c : a, b, c \in \Bbb{R} \}$ an inner product is given, $\langle p, q\rangle = \int\limits_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)\, \mathrm dx$, where $p, q \in \Bbb{R}_2[x]$. Determine one basis of orthogonal complement of the subspace $U = \mathcal{L}\{ x^2 - 1, x + 1\}$. Find an orthogonal projections of the polynomial $p(x) = 2x^2 + x + 5$ on the $U$ and $U^{\bot}$.

My method:

Because $U^{\bot} = \{ p \in \Bbb{R}_2[x]\,:\,(\forall q \in U):\langle p,q\rangle = 0 \}$, that means $\langle p, x^2- 1\rangle = 0$ and $\langle p, x + 1\rangle = 0$. That means I have to solve these two equations:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 (ax^2 + bx + c)(x^2 - 1) \,\mathrm dx = 0 \tag{1},$$ 
$$ \int_{-1}^1 (ax^2 + bx + c)(x + 1) \,\mathrm dx = 0 \tag{2}.$$
After solving $(1)$ I got $a = -5c, \, (b, c \in\Bbb{R})$ and after solving $(2)$ I got $b = 2c, \, c \in \Bbb{R}$.
Now I can conclude that $U^{\bot} = \{ (-5c)x^2 + 2cx + c : c \in \Bbb{R} \}$.

From there we have that for $p \in U^{\bot}$, $p(x) = c(-5x^2 + 2x + 1)$. Now I can conclude that $U^{\bot} = \mathcal{L}\{ -5x^2 + 2x + 1 \}$.

Question no.1.: Is $-5x^2 + 2x + 1$ a basis of $U^{\bot}$?

I tried to find  the orthogonal projections in the next way:
Let $q \in U,\, r \in U^{\bot}$. Let $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Bbb{R} $ and 
$$p(x) = q(x) + r(x) \Leftrightarrow 2x^2 + x + 5 = \alpha (x^2 - 1) + \beta (x + 1) + \gamma (-5x^2 + 2x + 1) \tag{3}$$

After solving $(3)$ and getting $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, now I have that:

1. $\alpha (x^2 - 1) + \beta (x + 1)$ is orthofgonal projection on $U$.
2. $\gamma (-5x^2 + 2x + 1)$ is orthogonal projection on $U^{\bot}$.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is right (I don't check the calculations). I got two relevant details:

**(detail 1)** One knows that $\dim\mathbb{R}_2 [x] = 3$ and $\{x^2-1,x+1\}$ is linearly independent, thus $\dim U = 2$ and $\dim U^{\perp} = 1$.

In that way, we can answer question 1: if your calculations are right, the set $\{-5x^2+2x+1\}$ is a basis for $U^{\perp}$.

**(detail 2)** When you write $p(x) = q(x)+r(x)$ you are using implicitly that $\mathbb{R}_2[x] = U + U^{\perp}$, and this is right since $\mathbb{R}_2[x] = U\oplus U^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. And the  answer to your question no.1 (which is curious, since there is no other question) is affirmative, too. It is always true that, if $v$ is non-zero vector of a vector space $V$, then $\{v\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{L}(v)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought there would be maybe more questons. :)